# Find 2 subarrays from an array of n elements that have equal or close to sum of their elements

Tags: algorithm, math

Let's say you have an array = [2, 3, 3, 6, 7], it is not sorted, but you can sort it if you would like. Find 2 subarrays using all the elements in the array so that the resulting subarrays will be [2, 3, 6] and [7, 3] since 2 + 3 + 6 = 11 and 7 + 3 = 10.

The sums of the resulting subarrays don't have to be equal but they should be as close as they can be.

My first approach was sorting this elements in desc order and taking elements from each end of the array.

Any help will be appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Here's a hint: let `S` be the sum of the entire array, it should be clear that this problem is the same as trying to find some subarray that gets as close to `S / 2` as possible.

Comment: yes, I thought of that but what if the last element is super large though. Is there maybe any established algorithms to do something similar already.

Comment: That's fine, it's sufficient to find a subarray that's strictly less than `S / 2` as well, so the problem is reduced to "Given an array of integers, pick a subarray such that the sum is maximized <= `k`" where `k = S / 2`. This should look very similar to a common CS problem.

Comment: True, and if I can find one subarray that equals or is close to the k then I can just get the remaining elements in the original array to be the second subarray.

Comment: Can we rearrange are at the beginning and define subarrays over the rearranged array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that this is a well-known problem known as the partition problem. For more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the sum of all the numbers is `N`. To determine whether there is a solution where the two subsets have equal sum is equivalent to the problem of determining whether there is a subset that adds to `N / 2`.

[The best known algorithms for this problem are exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).